# A question about rectifiable curves

Tags: general-topology

Does every rectifiable curve that is a subset of the Euclidean plane have zero two-dimensional Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Yes. For a very short (a few sentences) and elementary proof, see Burckel/Goffman, [*Rectifiable curves are of zero content*](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2689066), **Mathematics Magazine** 44 #4 (September 1971), 179-180.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I thought the answer should be. But I could not see a way to represent the rectifiable curve as a subset of the countable union of arbitrarily small rectangles.