# Does there exist a Lipschitz map from the unit interval onto the unit square?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, fractals

It is well-known that continuous space-filling curves exist.  But can they be Lipschitz?

Specifically, is there a Lipschitz map from [0,1] onto [0,1]x[0,1]?

Comment: Nope: The image of an interval under a Lipschitz mapping has Hausdorff dimension $1$, while the square does not.

Comment: Ok.  Strictly speaking, the image has dimension no greater than 1, right?  Also, an alternate proof using only simple analysis would be nice.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant to say.

Answer (score 3):

It's a general fact that if $f$ is a Lipschitz mapping, then the Hausdorff dimension satisfies

$$\dim_{H} f(F) \le \dim_H F$$

for all $F$. If $F$ is the unit interval, then $\dim_H F = 1$, while the Hausdorff dimension of the square is $2$; this means no such Lipschitz map can exist.

---

The above inequality can be found, e.g. as Corollary $2.4$ in Falconer's *Fractal Geometry*.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.  The answer I came up with doesn't mention Hausdorff dimension, although you might say it's there in disguise:

Suppose there is such a map.  Given a positive integer $N$, subdividing $[0,1]$ into $N$ equal intervals and considering the images of these will give a cover of $[0,1]^2$ having area $\leq NC/N^2$ where $C$ is a constant independent of $N$ (this is since the image of a sub-interval lies in a ball of diameter proportional to $1/N$).  Letting $N \to \infty$ gives $\big| [0,1]^2 \big|=0$, which cannot be.

Comment: FYI, I think your method may be related to the proof Goffman gives in the reference I provided at [A question about rectifiable curves](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/708186/a-question-about-rectifiable-curves), but I don't have (easy) access to the paper where I'm at right now to say for sure.